# Running js file only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small intro with fadein's etc.. But i would only like this to run once. I dont want to run the intro every time the user returns to the home page. Is there a way to run a js file once?

Comment: You could use cookies, but they're not reliable. IP tracking isn't perfect either. Local storage also requires the user's consent. Short answer: no.

Comment: There is this evil thingy called evercookie.

Comment: IF you show this only to logged in users, you can keep a flag in the db that tells you if you have shown the intro to that user before.  If you show this to logged out users too, it is way harder.

Comment: @Steve: But a logged in user has probably already seen the intro (or probably doesn't want to see it?!) - so may be they shouldn't be shown the intro in the first place?!

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Let's not be pessimistic. The client side _is_ the user's consent. This is web programming..

Comment: @w3d I missed the part about the "home page"... I was thinking that if it is happening only on a page that can be accessed after you logged in, then you could track it in the db.  But you are right, you can probably get to the home page even when logged out.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use HTML5 [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage) to record when the intro has once played. This memory will persist for the session:

```
var played = sessionStorage.getItem("played");

if ( played !== "true" ) {

    // play intro

    // mark as played when finished
    sessionStorage.setItem("played", "true");
}
```

Comment: Won't this suffer more incompatibilities than simply using a (session) cookie?

Comment: @w3d HTML5 is cool! Endorse the future. But realistically, check [this table](http://dev-test.nemikor.com/web-storage/support-test/); looks like 87% coverage. And if you're still using IE 6 or 7 you probably too old to remember that you've already watched the intro.

Answer (score 1):

When your intro function runs, first have it check for a cookie that you will set later.  If the cookie exists then the function should abort without displaying the effect.  If the cookie does not exist then display the effect and set the cookie.

Of course, this solution is only dependable per web browser installation (assuming cookies are enabled when they visit).  So if the same user visits the site in another browser they will likely see the effect again.  Conversely, if a new user uses a browser which has already visited the site then they will not see the effect.

It's not perfect but probably "good enough" - it covers the main use-case and is easy to implement.